# Can a service layer object in a Java Spring project call in a bean from the Application-Context.xml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Can a service layer object in a Java Spring project call in a bean from the Application-Context.xml?

```
public class MemberInquiryServiceImpl implements MemberInquiryService {

    private String BASE_URI;
    private String user;
    private String password;

    HttpResponse response;

    public MemberInquiryServiceImpl() {

        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();

        RequestTrackerConfig rtc = (RequestTrackerConfig) ctx
                .getBean("requestTrackerConfig");

        BASE_URI = rtc.getUrl();
        user = rtc.getUser();
        password = rtc.getPassword();

    }
```

Comment: Yes, of course.  Are you asking how to write the code to do so, or if it's an 'architecturally sound' practice, or...?

Answer (score 2):

> Can a service layer object in a Java Spring project call in a bean
>   from the Application-Context.xml?

Yes, but in your code you are creating a new ApplicationContext:

```
public MemberInquiryServiceImpl() {

        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
```

which I doubt is what you actually meant to do (I'm assuming your `MemberInquiryServiceImpl` is created by Spring).

Instead, you could for example autowire (using annotations or xml-config) the `RequestTrackerConfig` to `MemberInquiryServiceImpl`, or make `MemberInquiryServiceImpl` implement [ApplicationContextAware](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html) -interface, and use the injected ApplicationContext to get the "requestTrackerConfig" -bean.

Comment: Sounds to me like you are not completely confident with Springs' dependency injection/inversion of control -principles, perhaps read through the Chapter 3 of the documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html. There are also loads of tutorials and examples floating around the 'net about using ApplicationContextAware, autowiring and what not, for example: http://www.captaindebug.com/2011/06/using-springs-applicationcontextaware.html  http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-wiring-beans-with-autowired-annotation/

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you inject it using dependency injection?